# Create new "Stats" dimension using iccupe API / ExecuteMdxScript

Tags: iccube

I know how to create a new hierarchy on an existing dimension using [ExecuteMdxScript](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/api/ExecuteMdxScript.php) from the [IcCube API](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/api/index.php) using something like :

```
create category hierarchy [Groupe Spécifique].[NouvelleHierarchie], DEFAULT_MEMBER_NAME = "Tout"
```

Is there a possibility to create a new Dimension itself (which type would be "Stats") using this channel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is currently not possible.